# Forms in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I'm able to create ModelSeralizers easily, but I am having a little trouble with my Forms. Is there a way to serialize the form below, or do I need to do each form in the native language if I take this to a mobile device?

```
class SetPasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='New password',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                                    attrs={'placeholder': 'New password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Verify new password',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                                    attrs={'placeholder': 'Password again'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(SetPasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password_length = settings.MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        if len(password1) < password_length:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Password must be longer than "
                "{} characters".format(password_length))
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2:
            if password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
        return password2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a serializer named `PasswordSerializer` which performs the same checking and validation as you are doing above in `SetPasswordForm`.

We create a serializer having 2 fields `password1` and `password2`.

`password1` field has `min_length` argument passed to it which validates that the input contains no fewer than this number of characters. Also, we define the custom error message for the case in which input is less than `min_length` in an `error_messages` dictionary. Doing this removes the validations you were performing earlier in your form and now DRF will handle that for you. Also, the serializer fields have `allow_null` set to `False`. So, if `None` value is sent, DRF automatically handles that.

We need to create a `validate()` function which checks if the passwords match or not. If the 2 passwords do not match, serializer will raise a `ValidationError`.

The above code transformed to a DRF serializer will be something like:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class PasswordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    password1 = serializers.CharField(min_length=settings.MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH, error_messages={'min_length': "Password must be longer than {} characters".format(settings.MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH)})
    password2 = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password1'] != data['password2']: # Check if the 2 passwords match
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
        return data
```

Comment: Thank you for this! To clarify, I essentially have to re-create each form as a serializer? Obvious I can copy and paste a lot of the validators, but there's no way to reference the form is there?

Comment: Yes, you would have to recreate each form as a serializer. Serializers work very similar to Django forms. You can add the form validations in the serializers and they will work similarly like forms. And no, you use either a form or a serializer to achieve what you were doing before. You can't reference a form in your serializer, its unnecessary .